# What determines what gets put on the Community Bulletin?

Tags: support, community-bulletin

Enough said in the title, I'm wondering what determines what gets put in the Community Bulletin...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The community bulletin has the following items put on it. At least, I believe this is the full list.

1. Blog posts from the Arqade Blog within the past 2 weeks.
2. Events setup by moderators, during the time period setup for them.
3. Moderator elections, during the time period setup for them.
4. Meta questions that have [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) on them.
5. Recent active and viewed Meta questions, as determined by the "week" tab on the front page.

Comment: Doublechecked with another and, yeah, this is the full list.